# Scaffolding for an angular 1x Admin project

Tags: angularjs, scaffolding

**Which is the best scaffolding for an angular 1x Admin project?**

Comment: You can refer this https://medium.com/bitmaker-software/scaffolding-a-new-angularjs-project-db01151f16e0

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/SwiftySpartan/Angular-1.5-cli

This should satisfy what you're looking for.

Per the review tag below:
What you're looking for is something like Angular CLI.  However Angular CLI is only compatible with Angular.  If you search on GitHub you can probably find several scaffolding and/or client tool.  Or you could write your own with something like webpack, Grunt, or Gulp or a tool of your choosing.

The Angular CLI is a pretty useful client for Angular projects.  Doing something like this isn't terribly difficult.  It is just finding what fits your needs the best, hence writing your own.